# Excel VBA ADODB getting duplicates

Tags: sql, excel, duplicates, adodb

This one is driving me nuts.
I have an Excel add-in that a few people are using. One user keeps getting duplicates in the sql results...Here is the odd thing about it:

```
    SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " & SCHEMA & ".XR_" & chg & "_OUTBOUND WHERE Header = 1 OR OUTBOUND_BATCH_ID = " & BatchID & " ORDER BY HEADER DESC, CLAIM_NUMBER ASC"
    
    
    rs.Open SQL, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    wsMRC.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

I am using DISTINCT. When I run the sql in sql dev, no dups. There are no dupes on my machine or the other 2 people using it. Just ONE user is getting dupes!
The dupes ALWAYS start at row 101 and its not ALL rows.. just some.

I checked their pc, they have the same Oracle versions, same Excel versions.. I turned off all other Add-ins...I tried using a for next loop instead...
I am 100% baffled. Need help!

Comment: And you are aware of that DISTINCT is used to get distinct _rows_?

Comment: yes. the entire rows are duplicates. The SQL for everyone else gets no dupes with or without the distinct, but I added it to try to make sure there were no duplicate rows, but for one user, there are. So confused.

Comment: Are you certain that data doesn't already exist on the `wsMRC` worksheet before you `CopyFromRecordset`? that method merely overwrites data up to whatever the last row in your `rs` is. So if the table once had 101 records and one was deleted from the table and the sheet wasn't cleared, that 101 row will still be populated in excel and only the 100 previous rows will be overwritten with `CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: yes im sure. the code creates a new workbook/worksheet every time. I can run it 10x in a row on her pc and it gets dups, 10x on mine and no dupes. lol.

Comment: Did you compare the SQL-strings from both computers. E.g. are `SCHEMA` different or `chg`. Does the user have the same rights on the DB itself or e.g. different user group?

Comment: everything is exactly the same. If you take the query (from the debug.print) and drop it into SQL DEV and run it.. it gets the correct results with no dupes. Its something going on in excel...